# find the limit of sequence $\ln(n) ^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification

I'm not sure if I can use the squeeze theorem???

I did the following, not sure if it's correct

$$1^{1/n} < \ln(n)^{1/n} < n^{1/n}$$ for n greater than or equal to 3 
 and as  $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 1^{1/n} = 1\qquad \text{and}\qquad
\lim_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n} = 1\qquad \text{(it's a fact)}$$
 then $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \ln(n)^{1/n} = 1$$ ??????

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: Yes, that is a correct application of the queen theorem.

Comment: @Jason   Queen? I seem to be missing a joke or something.

Comment: @zhw. Nope, just an autocorrect (squeeze theorem) that I didn't notice, nobody else corrected, and apparently got two upvotes?

Comment: @Jason But I do like the idea of the "queen theorem". "Squeeze" is getting too politicized these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes **it is correct**.

As an alternative:

$$(\ln n)^{\frac1n}=e^{\frac1n\ln (\ln n)}\to e^0=1$$

**NOTE**

in general when you have expression like $A^B$ it can be useful transform in the equivalent expression:

$$A^B=e^{ln A^B}=e^{B\ln A}$$

Comment: Did you intend an exponent of $\frac{1}{n}\ln(\ln n)$?

Comment: ops thanks it was a typo :(

Comment: That may have been the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: Yes of course, even if a little bit too severe for an apparent typo, anyway thank you so much for the advice,I would never have seen it without your intervention!

Comment: I agree. It's better to just point out an apparent typo than to downvote. Seems mean-spirited.

Comment: We are here to learn, I do not care to make mistakes but I would be very sorry not to learn anything! Thanks a lot, you are a very kind person.

Comment: I downvoted this answer, and it wasn't because of the typo. The limit in question can be proved using relatively elementary tools of analysis, which is what the OP was trying to do. Your answer requires continuity of $\exp$, the relationship $\exp^{-1}=\log$, and the limit $\frac1n\log\log n\to0$. These facts all require proof, and such proofs would typically appear much later in an analysis course.

Comment: @Jason I don't know what level aud999 was looking for, I only notice that the given limits do not seems elementary to me, it contains a log and maybe aud999 knows what a log is about, and also the proos by squeeze theorem needs a proof, and what about the limit $n^{\frac1n}$ it a fact? doesn't need a proof? all need a proof in math exept axioms! My answer was aimed to give an others well known method of solution which maybe will be useful to aud999 in the future. In any case he accepted the answer and thus maybe he believes that it was an useful answer, that's what matters to me. Thanks.